# Response.Redirect to same page without Page Refresh

Tags: .net, asp.net, html, redirect, postback

I need to do a response.redirect to the same page.  How can I do this without the page "refreshing" or "flashing"?  I can't use updatepanels because, this is a search website and I want the user to be able to use the browser's back button.  I have some search filters on the page, and each time a filter is clicked, I do a resposne.redirect (to the same page) with the appropriate query strings.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The only way you can do this without a "flicker" or "refresh" if you will is to do an AJAX call and update all your necessary fields. Otherwise `Response.Redirect()` will flicker your page.

Comment: is there a way to do this and still maintain the history of calls?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [EnableHistory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.enablehistory.aspx) property of the ScriptManager control.  Introduced in .NET 3.5 SP1, it allows the browser to maintain a history points for partial postbacks.  This means the user can navigate through these history points through use of the forward/back buttons on their browser.